# Java GridBagLayout components centering when background filled

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to create a GridBagLayout, I have got the panels set out exactly how I want them. However I cannot set the background colour of each panel without also forcing all of the components to center.

Here the panels are coloured but all of the components center
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEKXY.png

Here all of the components snap to NORTHWEST as specified in the code but the background color does not fill the pane.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAyFt.png

Sorry I cannot embed the pictures, my reputation is not high enough :(

```
    GridBagConstraints GBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    GBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;



    //green panel
    GBC.gridx = 0;
    GBC.gridy = 0;
    GBC.weightx = 0.1;
    GBC.weighty = 0.1;      

    JPanel panelGreen = new JPanel();
    panelGreen.setBackground(Color.green);          

    //add button to green panel
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    panelGreen.add(button, GBC);

    contentPane.add(panelGreen, GBC);



    //blue panel
    GBC.gridx = 1;
    GBC.gridy = 0;
    GBC.weighty = 0.1;  
    GBC.weightx = 0.9;      

    JPanel panelBlue = new JPanel();
    panelBlue.setBackground(Color.blue);        
    contentPane.add(panelBlue, GBC);




    //red panel
    GBC.gridx = 0;
    GBC.gridy = 1;      
    GBC.weighty = 0.8;
    GBC.weightx = 0.1;

    JPanel panelRed = new JPanel();
    panelRed.setBackground(Color.red);  
    contentPane.add(panelRed, GBC);



    //black panel
    GBC.gridx = 0;
    GBC.gridy = 2;      
    GBC.weighty = 0.1;
    GBC.weightx = 0.1;
    GBC.gridwidth =2;   

    JPanel panelBlack = new JPanel();
    panelBlack.setBackground(Color.black);          
    contentPane.add(panelBlack, GBC);




    //yellow panel
    GBC.gridx = 1;
    GBC.gridy = 1;      
    GBC.weighty = 0.8;
    GBC.weightx = 0.9;
    GBC.gridwidth =1;   

    JPanel panelYellow = new JPanel();
    panelYellow.setBackground(Color.yellow);        
    contentPane.add(panelYellow, GBC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, creating a JPanel() with the default constructor means it gets a FlowLayout - you need to tell your panels to use GridBagLayouts:

```
JPanel panelGreen = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

Other than that, you just need to have the "fill" property set to NONE when you add your JButton or it will expand to fill the whole pane. After you've added the button you can set it to BOTH for the panels themselves:

```
GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
panelGreen.add(button, GBC);

GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
contentPane.add(panelGreen, GBC);
```